# Reading a list of string from a .txt file

Tags: files

I have a file, `myfile.txt`, whose content is:

```
(query-replace "foo" "Hello" nil (point-min) (poin-max))
```

and this function:

```el
(defun comment-string-from-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((STRING (with-temp-buffer 
           (insert-file-contents "myfile.txt")
           (buffer-string))))

    (when (string-match (regexp-quote STRING) (buffer-string))
      (let ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
        (e (copy-marker (match-end 0))))

    (comment-region b e)))))
```

This function works and, if present, comments, in the current buffer, the string:

```el
"(query-replace \"foo\" \"Hello\" nil (point-min) (poin-max))"
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing looping over a file that contains a list of strings, separated by 2 newlines, e.g.

```
(query-replace "foo" "Hello" nil (point-min) (poin-max))

(query-replace "bar" "World" nil (point-min) (poin-max))

(insert "foo\n")

(insert "bar\n")
```

Alternatively, and this should be my first choice, I could use an arbitrary string boundary to allow newlines in my strings, e.g..

```
♦(query-replace "foo" 
           "Hello" nil (point-min) (poin-max))♦

♦(query-replace "bar" 
           "World" nil (point-min) (poin-max))♦

♦(insert "foo\n")♦

♦(insert "bar\n")♦
```

The idea is that I don't want to use any kind of escaping in the source file.

How can I do it?

Comment: This feels a bit convoluted, and I'm not sure I understand correctly what the *output* is supposed to be.  I can see that the input is the contents of `myfile.txt`, but can you please show the resulting contents of the output buffer (as you would like it to appear)?

Comment: Ah, I see now.  `myfile.txt` is a set of patterns, and you want to match those patterns *in the current buffer* (whatever that is), and comment out the matching regions.

Comment: @phils Yes. I want to comment the matching regions. I'll use it in temp-buffer. I need it to "filter" a file to ignoring/inhibiting some regions to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Elisp function covers all your use-cases.
You can choose two newlines as separator regexp `sep`. That is the default.
Or you can also choose some other character as separator regexp, such as `♦`. Empty strings between two separators are removed from the list `string-list` of regexps matching patterns to be commented-out. So your alternative pattern file syntax should work.

The patterns are combined to one regexp through `regexp-opt`.
You can comment all occurrences of the patterns by calling `comment-string-from-file` with prefix arg. Otherwise only the first occurrence of each pattern is replaced (such as your code example indicates).

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun comment-string-from-file (file &optional sep all)
  "Read patterns separated by SEP from FILE, comment out matching regions.
Comment all matches if ALL is non-nil.
Comment only first one if ALL is nil."
  (interactive "fPattern file: \nsSeparator regexp: \nP")
  (unless sep
    (setq sep "\n\n+"))
  (let* ((string (with-temp-buffer
                   (insert-file-contents file)
                   (buffer-string)))
         (string-list (cl-remove-if
                       (lambda (str)
                         (string-match "\\`[[:space:]\n]*\\'" str))
                       (split-string string sep)))
         (re (regexp-opt string-list)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (and
              string-list
              (re-search-forward re nil t))
        (let ((match (match-string 0)))
          (comment-region
           (match-beginning 0)
           (match-end 0))
          (unless all
            (setq string-list (cl-remove match string-list :test #'string-equal)
                  re (regexp-opt string-list))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll study it carefully! Do I need a common lisp package?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I have added `(require 'cl-lib)`. That is all you need from `cl`.

Comment: `[[:space:]\n]` could probably also be `[[:blank:]]`, and `(lambda (str) (string-match ...))` could probably be `#'string-blank-p` from `subr-x.el`.

Comment: @Basil No, `[[:blank:]]` matches horizontal whitespace. Newline is explicitly excluded: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/tr18-19.html#blank

Comment: @Tobias Oops, right you are. In that case shouldn't you also include `\r`, as per `string-blank-p`?

Comment: @Basil Luckily the carriage return character `\r` does not play any substantial role in Emacs buffers. The buffer text is always encoded in `utf-8-emacs`. Line end in that encoding is just Newline. The buffer text is converted at reading from and writing to file.

Comment: @Tobias That's great, thanks for explaining.